# How to detect if user paired with a BLE device using the Android Bluetooth settings?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

My app allows users to pair with specific BLE devices fine, but if my app is put in the background and the user pairs (or unpairs) with the BLE device using the Android bluetooth settings, my app is not aware of this. I've tried using ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST, but my receiver never receives it. Would someone illustrate how to do this, or point me at example code that does?

Comment: when you start your app and pair your device first time at that time what is the value of autoConnection value in `BluetoothGatt.connectGatt()` method? you may receive CallBack on `BluetoothGattCallback()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED) instead.
I don't know if that's the case but be aware of [Implicit broadcasts restriction](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions). Some broadcasts cannot be registered in AndroidManifest.xml anymore.